# NSBundle -- finding resources within a bundle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsbundle

I created a directory MyDirectory inside a bundle myBundle.  I then put an image myImage.png inside MyDirectory.  But a call to

```
 [myBundle pathForResource: @"myImage" ofType: @"png"]
```

does not find the image.  What am I missing?

EDIT:  To clarify, if the image is in the top level of the bundle, it finds it just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must have added the image to the bundle. If you've did it, I guess you would have added folder references while you added the image to the project. If so, you should specify the folder hierarchy with the image name.

```
[myBundle pathForResource:@"MyDirectory/myImage" ofType:@"png"];
```

Edit: As Deepak commented below, there is even a better method *pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:*

```
[myBundle pathForResource:@"myImage" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"MyDirectory"];
```

Comment: +1 a better method to use would be `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the image to your Xcode project (project.pbxproj)?